# Is this update, select combination query thread safe?

Tags: mysql, multithreading

I have a table called seats, which has a schema like this

> id,taken

For each user, I take a random untaken id and assign to that user, here for simplicity say, I make taken =1. The query I am using

```
   update seats u inner join  (
        SELECT id from seats  
        where taken is null limit 1) s 
   on s.id = u.id set taken = 1;
```

This query takes a random seat with taken flag null, and for that seat it makes the flag 1. While this query is working fine, is this  thread safe?

Consider this scenario, I have two users in parallel. For user1, I select row X, and just before update query is ran user2 checks in, and for that user select query returns the same row as user1. So I will end updating the same row twice.

Is this scenario possible with this query?

Comment: which programming language you are using with mysql?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP I am using php. But isn't the question langauge independent.

Comment: You can try something like SELECT ... FOR UPDATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With mysql, there's a simple, almost unbelievable, solution:

```
update seats set taken = 1
where taken is null
limit 1
```

This syntax limits the number of rows affected by the update process to 1, achieving your intention using mysql's special extension to the update syntax.

Naturally, being an officially supported extension, this is an atomic action and completely threadsafe.

Although neither your code nor your question suggests being able to capture *which* id was updates, you can capture it via a User Defined Variable:

```
update seats set
taken = 1,
id = (@id := id)
where taken is null
limit 1;

select @id id;
```

The value returned from the select will either the id that was updated or null if no row was updated.

Comment: I agree, this is more simple and intuitive. However, just for my understanding of databases, is the query I posted in the question atomic as well?

Comment: Also, in your method how will I know which seat_id has been taken?

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, all the SQL commands you can run within any RDBMS are thread safe, as long as it a server we are talking about and each thread is using its own connection. In fact database servers are created exactly for this purpose.

The only problem you might face for concurrently accessing a database server by two or more threads / processes, is dead locks. And that's a problem you can prevent within the logic of your program. Dead locks happen when one connection holds a resource (a record or table as for the databases) and asks for another while some other connection is going to acquire the same both resources in reverse order. These two connections will wait for the other one to release their resources which in theory could extend forever. MySQL resolves this issue by granting a lock for some limited time.

If you are to prevent dead locks, the easiest solution is to consider an order for acquiring locks. That way it's impossible for two connections to face each other.

Going back to your SQL statement, my answer is the same as Bohemian's which is complete. If you insist on it being random you can also:

```
UPDATE seats
SET
    taken = 1
WHERE
    taken IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

It's just that you need to know `WHERE taken IS NULL` is a really bad thing. If you want to search for a field, it should always be `NOT NULL`, specially if locks are involved. Perhaps you can assign `0` instead of `NULL`, it will boost the performance by a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would just recommand to do before the "UPDATE" the following query

```
SET @id = NULL
```

It's to be sure that the variable "@id" value is defined and reset to a specific values to manage the case when you run several times the "UPDATE / SELECT" query in the same connection.

Without that, you could have a wrong value if the UPDATE updates nothing and a previous UPDATE did work. It will keep in "@id" the old value